# How the execution of the if and else works inside while statement in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, sorting

```
while (S!=[] and (arr[S[len(S)-1]] <= arr[i]  
        if (order=='G') else  arr[S[len(S)-1]] >= arr[i] )):
       print("bla")
```

1)I want to know when print statement gets called

2)How the execution order of the code and working sequence of if and else

3)I never seen any condition after else these is the first time i have seen

4) The following code snippet is taken from
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-next-smaller-next-greater-array/

5) can we simplify the above conditions ?

Comment: It is a ternary operator which means either the true expression or the false expression will be evaluated based on the condition, so if `order == 'G` then the `while` condition becomes: `S!=[] and arr[S[len(S)-1]] <= arr[i]`, otherwise the `while` condition is `S!=[] and arr[S[len(S)-1]] >= arr[i]`

Comment: Thanks 
But can you tell  how will it evaluate  (how the following code goes to if  condition first without ) means what i want to do alter the first condition using if and else is it possible (sorry i am trying to be me accurate in understanding )

Answer (score 0):

Let's deconstruct the code a bit:

```
while (S!=[] and (arr[S[len(S)-1]] <= arr[i]  
        if (order=='G') else  arr[S[len(S)-1]] >= arr[i] )):
       print("bla")
```

can be rewritten as:

```
if order == 'G':
    while (S!=[] and arr[S[len(S)-1]] <= arr[i]):
        print('bla')
else:
    while (S!=[] and arr[S[len(S)-1]] >= arr[i]):
        print('bla')
```

Now, to start answering:

1. The print statement gets called as long as `S` is not empty and the value in `arr` on the last position in `S` is greater than the value in `arr` on the `i`th position. Since this is python, we can rewrite `arr[S[len(S)-1]]` as `arr[S[-1]]`, if that helps.
2. The if-else inline statement in Python works like this: `a = 2 if condition else 3`. If condition is truthy, a will be 2; otherwise, it'll be 3. This is why it can be rewritten as such:

```
if condition:
    a = 2
else:
    a = 3
```

To be clear, even in its inline form, Python *firstly evaluates the condition* and only then chooses the value. To give an example of what I'm trying to say, this is ok:

```
a = <thing that raises an exception> if <thing that is False> else <valid thing> 
# a will be <valid thing>, no exceptions will be raised.
```

5. The snippet *alone* can't really be simplified more than:

```
if order == 'G':
    while (S!=[] and arr[S[-1]] <= arr[i]):
        print('bla')
else:
    while (S!=[] and arr[S[-1]] >= arr[i]):
        print('bla')
```

As for 3. and 4., I'm not sure what to answer.